# Size of the Set in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, size

I have a set and I want to get the size of this set in VueJS and I am going to use it for the page navigation.My problem is I cannot use **size** to find the size of the object.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            numberOfPages: this.weeks.size,
            weeks: new Set(),
            tickets: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    time: "09:45",
                    date: new Date(),
                    name: "Swimming in the hillside pond",
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    time: "09:45",
                    date: new Date(),
                    name: "Swimming in the hillside pond",
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        currentNumberOfWeek(tickets) {
            tickets.forEach(ticket => {
                let result = this.getWeekNumber(ticket.date);
                this.weeks.add(result)
            });
            this.sortSet(this.weeks);
            console.log(this.weeks);
        },
        getWeekNumber(date) {
            const oneJan = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            const numberOfDays = Math.floor((date - oneJan) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            let weekNumber = Math.ceil((date.getDay() + 1 + numberOfDays) / 7);
            return weekNumber;
        },
        sortSet(set) {
            const entries = [];
            for (const member of set) {
                entries.push(member);
            }
            set.clear();
            for (const entry of entries.sort()) {
                set.add(entry);
            }
            return set;
        },
    },
};
```

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined" and I dont know why I am getting it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to handle this is to use a computed property.

```
var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        weeks: new Set()
    },
    computed: {
        weeksSize(){
            return this.weeks.size
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can use your "weeksSize" also in your methods with "this.weeksSize".

Check [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for computed property for more informations.

Comment: Thanks but when I try to use it inside the v-for, I am getting "weeksSize is not a function". I am trying to use it like this: <li
                    class="page-item"
                    v-for="n in weeksSize()"
                    v-bind:class="{ active: currPage === n }"
                    @click.prevent="setPage(n)"
                >
                    <a class="page-link" href="">{{ n }}</a>
                </li>

Comment: Just remove the bracket. <li class="page-item" v-for="n in weeksSize">. weeksSize returns an Integer

Answer (score 1):

You need a computed property in this case.

```
{
  data(){return {weeks: new Set()}},
  computed:{numberOfPages:()=>this.weeks.size}
}
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties